# Каким образом можно сохранить при повороте экрана view компонента?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, android-view

Для сохранения при повороте экрана использую метод

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //outState.putInt("count", cnt);
    Log.d("myLog", "onSaveInstanceState");
}
```

А можно как то сохранить view элемент ? а если конкретнее то EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сохранить информацию об элементе и только, поскольку при повороте экрана все методы жизненного цикла срабатывают заново.

Однако, если поместите ваш `EditText` в фрагмент, установите в теле метода `onCreateView()` флаг `setOnRetainInstance(true);` - то при повороте экрана будет уничтожаться лишь `view` представление, но данные будут оставаться. Иначе говоря на время фрагмент открепляется, сохраняя всё своё внутреннее состояние, затем пересоздается по текущим параметрам.

Думаю, как альтернатива может сработать.

Answer (score 1):

За сохранение содержимого конкретно в виджете `EditText` при повортое экрана отвечают методы базового класса и дополнительных усилий по его сохранению (кроме вызова `super.*` для методов жизненного цикла) от программиста не требуется